# AWS Route 53 DNS - IP address could not be found

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, webserver, amazon-route53

I hope to use my DNS: jwyoungs.com
I purchased the domain last year using AWS Route 53 but I didn't have a chance to set up a website.
I am planning to use EC2 instance for my web server and I assigned an Elastic IP address (18.188.179.120) for my domain, as instructed.

I have created hosted zones and I matched the name servers in the hosted zone with my registered domain.

When I turn on my web server using nodejs, I can connect it with my IP address but my Domain is not working.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DNS Records could take a while to propagate depending on which DNS server you are using (usually 10s of minutes to hours). I just pinged your DNS name, and I got the correct IP resolution using CloudFlare's DNS.

```
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   jwyoungs.com
Address: 18.188.179.120
```

Comment: Yes. It took about 15 minutes for the browser to find my server.